# \uppercase doesn't work around text-generating command

Tags: tex-core

```
    \newcommand{\testcommand}{A foo Bar.}
    \uppercase{abc}
    \uppercase{\testcommand}
```

Produces

> ABC A foo Bar.

instead of

> ABC A FOO BAR.

Why, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to expand the `\testcommand` first, since `\uppercase` performs the change of characters on a token level.

Better use `\MakeUppercase{\testcommand}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\testcommand}{A foo Bar.}
\uppercase{abc}
\uppercase\expandafter{\testcommand}

\MakeUppercase{\testcommand}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: try the two alternatives with `a foo Stra\ss e` :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: True, it will remain `ß` for the `\expandafter` version, but that's not bad, since there will be a uppercase `ß` in future in German language/alphabet. (I know, the displayed character is not an uppercase `ß` ;-)

Comment: But even if you use a font with an uppercase \ss (any T1 encoded font for example) `\uppercase` will not uppercase `\ss` as it is not a character token.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I don't expect that a `\detokenize` and weird expansion will cure this problem?

Comment: By the way, the `\expandafter` before `\uppercase` is redundant.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you could add enough code that you implement `\MakeUppercase`, yes:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Well, no, I could copy the code from `latex.ltx` then... no need

Answer (score 7):

Why? Is just because that is how it is defined, it is a token level transformation and the token `\testcommand` is unchanged , it only affects character tokens.

You should use `\MakeUppercase`, a latex command that expands before uppercasing, and makes other adjustments.